# Inequality with a,b,c >0 with GM

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, radicals

I have this inequality: for every $a,b,c > 0$ prove that
$$ \frac{1}{a+2b}+\frac{1}{b+2c}+\frac{1}{c+2a}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$
I have tried AM-GM, C-B-S and other ones. Please give me a hint.
This is what I have tried: 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+2b}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{9}(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b}) $$
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+2b}\leq \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$ but 
$\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt[3]{abc}\leq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}} $ and it's not true.

Comment: Oh, since you've tried all that, please edit your post to include your workings from each of those attempts!  Please give us some work?

Comment: this would help if we can Show that $$\frac{1}{a+2b}+\frac{1}{b+2c}+\frac{1}{c+2a}\le \frac{3}{a+b+c}$$

Comment: Is the inequality correct...? When $b$ is large enough but $a=c=1$, the left side is at least $1/3$, while the right side approaches to $0$...

Comment: If I can prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+2b}\leq \frac{3}{a+b+c}$ then is just AM-GM.

Answer (score 4):

it's wrong!

Try $$(a,b,c)=(100,0.1,0.1).$$

Comment: Do not post a solution. Please give me a hint. Because a want to try to solve it myself.